# Why is the cyclic group just generated by a single element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know the definition of a cyclic group after I learned a group generated by a set. A cyclic group is a group generated by a single element. But why we can't generate a cyclic group by a set that has more than one element?

Comment: You can always generate any (non-trivial) group with a set that has more than one element, namely $G=\left\langle G\right\rangle$. The special thing about cyclic groups is that you can generate them using only one!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you read a compact phrase like

> a group generated by a single element

You should interpret that to mean:

> a group such that *there exists* a single-element set that generates the group

But **not**:

> a group whose generating set has a single element

The latter interpretation is syntactically sound, and it sounds plausible if you haven't studied groups before. But it implicitly assumes that a group *has* a distinguished generating set, so that you can speak of "the" generating set of a group. Generally speaking, this is not the case. So the former interpretation is the only one that makes sense.

Indeed, the generating sets, plural, of a group can be very different from each other. See the other answers for examples.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it now.

Comment: For example, any nonzero element of $(\mathbb{Z}_p, +)$ for prime $p$ will generate this group.  Edit: just saw other answers.  Oh well.

Answer (score 11):

We can - who said we couldn't? You can even have irredundant generating sets with more than one element. For example $C_6 = \langle g \rangle = \langle g^2,g^3 \rangle$, where $g$ has order $6$.

Comment: I can't upvote your answer, but I want to say thank you. This is my first question.

Answer (score 2):

A set with more than one element can be a generator of a cyclic group. Consider for example the (additive) group $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. It is cyclic, because it is generated by the set {1}. But it is also generated by any of the sets {1, 3, 5} or {2, 3}. The important part is that it is possible th generate the group by a singleton.

As a counterexample consider the group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ which is not cyclic.

Comment: Thank you, I understood.